# How to pass type value to a variable with the type reflect.Type Golang

Tags: go, types, reflection

I need to create StructField, in which I need to pass reflect.Type value for the Type field. I would like to pass other types like reflect.Bool, reflect.Int to function which will be used in the construction of StructField. I cannot do this with the code below

```
reflect.StructField{
            Name: strings.Title(v.Name),
            Type: reflect.Type(reflect.String),
            Tag:  reflect.StructTag(fmt.Sprintf(`xml:"%v,attr"`, v.Name)),
        }
```

Because it

```
Cannot convert an expression of the type 'Kind' to the type 'Type'
```

How would I accomplish it?

Comment: To create a `reflect.Type` value from a `reflect.Kind` value you should do a switch on the `reflect.Kind` and based on the case initialialize the appropriate `reflect.Type`. i.e. `switch k { case reflect.Int64: return reflect.TypeOf(int64(0)) ...`.

Comment: Or you can use a map equivalent to the switch mentioned above: https://play.golang.org/p/BbK5A1SEHJN

Comment: Is there a better way to pass types (like types.Bool) to function and immediately transmit it to the construction, without switch or map?

Comment: In Go you cannot pass around types. Also note that `reflect.Bool` is *not* a type, it is a value. (don't know about types.Bool, don't know what `types` package you imply)

Comment: @mkopriva He's likely referring to [`types.Bool`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Bool).

Comment: @icza probably yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) is a type, and so the expression

```
reflect.Type(reflect.String)
```

Would be a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). Type of `reflect.String` is [`reflect.Kind`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind) which does not implement the interface type `reflect.Type`, so the conversion is invalid.

The `reflect.Type` value representing `string` is:

```
reflect.TypeOf("")
```

Generally the `reflect.Type` descriptor of any (non-interface) type can be acquired using the [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) function if you have a value of it:

```
var x int64
t := reflect.TypeOf(x) // Type descriptor of the type int64
```

It's also possible if you don't have a value. Start from a typed `nil` pointer value, and call `Type.Elem()` to get the *pointed type*:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*int64)(nil)).Elem()      // Type descriptor of type int64

t2 := reflect.TypeOf((*io.Reader)(nil)).Elem() // Type descriptor of io.Reader
```